# Unable to add eventListener in javascript to the arrow created by css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an image slider content using html, css and javascript. For moving to the next and previous images i have created arrows using css and they appear in the web page. But when trying to add an eventListener to that arrow, it shows unable to add. Below are my html and css code:

```js
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
let arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left");
let arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right");
let current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Init slider
function startSlide() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}

// Show next
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
});

// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

```css
.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

#arrow-left {
  border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#arrow-right {
  border-width: 30px 0 30px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow">.</div>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span>Welcome to Bruno's Pizzeria</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span>Welcome to Bruno's Pizzeria</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide3">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span>Welcome to Bruno's Pizzeria</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow">.</div>
</div>
```

The browser shows the below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at slider.js:34
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The code seems fine if I run it

Comment: Which line is that ? "at slider.js:34"

Comment: Make sure you run this code after the document.ready event has fired. You're trying to get the element before it has been created, which is why it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript is correct. But I think the problem is in the sequence of loading the webpage. For your code to work properly you need to make sure the javascript file loads after the HTML file is rendered completely (since it uses DOM elements).

Here are some ways to make sure the JavaScript file loads after the HTML

- Add the script tag after or just before the closing body tag

```
...
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

- Add `defer` attribute in the script tag

```
<head>
...
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
...
```

- Use load event of window as

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        // your complete code
})

// OR

window.onload = function(){
       // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

include your `slider.js` file at last of HTML body tag. Because arrow-left & arrow-right DOM element will have access only after it loaded.

```js
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
let arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left");
let arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right");
let current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Init slider
function startSlide() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}

// Show next
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
});

// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

```css
.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

#arrow-left {
  border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#arrow-right {
  border-width: 30px 0 30px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"><<</div>
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span>Welcome to Bruno's Pizzeria 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span>Welcome to Bruno's Pizzeria 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide3">
      <div class="slide-content">
        <span>Welcome to Bruno's Pizzeria 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow">>></div>
</div>
```